# IdentityServer4 - Azure - Kestrel?... Timeouts

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, identityserver4

So we are having load issues and not much clue why... if I pummel my server with a web performance test - it will be happy under little load - but if i pump it up we end up with timeouts and errors.

It might be hosting related as we are using Azure
It might be IdentityServer4 related as that is what we use for Auth
It might be code related elsewhere.

Errors - this is the first error we see.

```
Status Code 408 - on this Url /Identity/Account/Login
```

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.PumpAsync() at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException() at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result) at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult() at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBufferAsync() at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormReader.BufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormReader.ReadNextPairAsyncImpl(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormReader.ReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.FormValueProviderFactory.AddValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IList`1 factories) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ControllerContext controllerContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

The we get another probably because of this one happening already but popping here just incase on the following url

```
/connect/token
```

We have added this `.UseIISIntegration()` on the app start up as read azure apps required it. we have also tried looking into modifiying the kestrels timeout properties like so

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate =
                    new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                options.Limits.MinResponseDataRate =
                    new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            })
```

other than that - we have tried upping bits of infrastrure - eg - SQL db tier, AzureApp tiers. Some have got rid of other issue we had - eg db timeouts - but this issue still remains.

If you need any more info I can try to dig it out.
Thanks in advance,
Adrian

Comment: It feels like something upstream is throttling. Could it be some sort of DoS/flood protection kicking in?

Comment: @mackie interesting - let me check that